# Library to map Javascript classes to Java classes

Tags: javascript, java

I work with automated front-end testing using [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) quite frequently. One webdriver method I need to use a lot is [`webDriver.executeScript("some jQuery stuff usually")`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

My problem is that using this method is pretty difficult: no autocomplete, multiple statements are hard, embedded strings become messy fast, etc. So much like it's nice to have a jQuery class in Javascript, it would be nice to have a jQuery class in Java.

I know there are several existing pieces of software which wrap popular existing libraries like [jQuery](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/) and [Underscore.js](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java), but I don't know of a generic library which converts Javascript classes to Java classes.

I created a [pretty basic implementation](https://github.com/MichaelSnowden/js2j) to demonstrate what I'm looking for. It works pretty easily because JS lets you inspect all the functions of a class, all the functions of its prototype, and [AngularJS's method for annotating functions is publicly available](https://gist.github.com/Rafe/33cf0fb9728d0753ac39).

For example, running `JS2J.generate("$")` will create [this Java class](https://gist.github.com/MichaelSnowden/f008d3cfef6beb68716f).

I have searched for "javascript to java class converter", but I couldn't find any library which does what I want, which is **generate a Java class from a Javascript class**.